# Finding the best "deal" in a "group buy", given a table of values

Tags: php, python, math

Using **PHP** or **Python**, but I'm sure the basic functions are agnostic.

I am unsure what the proper term, mathematical theory, or algorithm is, otherwise I'm sure Google would have fixed this for me in minutes.

I have a data set similar to the following:

```
cost | qty | ppl | store
------------------------
   30|  500|   10|     1
   40|  600|   12|     2
   35|  500|   14|     3
   50|  700|   10|     1
   30|  700|   12|     1
   40|  250|   14|     2
```

What I'm trying to do is find the "optimal" row, based on these qualifiers:

- cost: lower is better.
- qty: higher is better.
- ppl: lower is better.
- store: Doesn't matter in this case, but used later to find "best" depending on 'store'.

Essentially, I'm trying to find the best particular "deal" in a "group buy"-like situation, where the fewest amount of people are required to get the best "value" (quantity -vs- cost).

To my eye, it appears that the best-overall would be Row #5, because of the jump in quantity.

If there is a name for this, and a good (Wikipedia?) article on the subject, I'd be happy to finish this myself. Thanks for your time!

Comment: jimbob helped to point out that I may not have been clear about what each field/number is representative of. Cost here is a total cost per each person, quantity is the number of items received by *each* person (pieces of candy?) and "ppl"/people is the number of people required in order to get that particular deal. Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: With this scenario there isn't a "correct" answer.  You should model a little bit more your problem. for example: Duplicating the cost or the ppl is as bad as dividing the qty per 2 ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute `qty / (cost * ppl)` and sort the list by that number. This number will be higher for higher `qty` and lower `cost` and `ppl`.

You might want to use something like this (python):

```
def cmp(a, b):
    return (a["qty"] / (a["cost"] * a["ppl"])) - (b["qty"] / (b["cost"] * b["ppl"]))

list = sorted(list, cmp)
```

**Explanation**: think what happens if `qty` is getting bigger when `cost * ppl` are constant. The ratio will increase, because `a/x > b>x` if `a > b`. Now with the other two values it's the other way around; if `x/a > x/b`, then `a < b`, so the ratio would actually get *decreased* when `cost` or `ppl` increases (think what happens if you split 100$ to two people vs three people; if you split it to two, each will get 100/2 = 50$. If you split it to three, each will get 100/3 ~= 33$, which is less). (Sorry if i'm not making it clear enough; i'm tired)

Comment: prefer passing a `key` parameter to `sorted` instead of `cmp` (which you forgot to pass).

Comment: @Jon-Eric oops, fixed. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to work as intended. Any chance someone can point me to an explanation on *why* this works? I'm not sure how to phrase that question, but essentially I'm a little math-illiterate (and trying to fix that problem!). This solution seems to work fine, but I'd like to be able to come up with this stuff on my own, have a better understanding of the math behind it (as elementary as it may be), etc.

Comment: your criteria for optimality is both directly proportional to quantity and inversely proportional to cost and 'ppl'. The result `"qty / (cost * ppl)"` for each row is an indicator of this optimality. Comparing each row to each other based on this number gets you the result you want.

Comment: Thanks Adriano, and especially Gabi for adding explanations! Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) in general, and the [simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) in particular.

Comment: Thanks for the resource! I'm a little bit math-illiterate, so the simplex algorithm article is a bit tough to read. Doing my best!

Comment: @anon: I'm doing a maths degree and I find the simplex algorithm hard to understand! Fortunately the difficult work has already been done, because this is a very standard sort of problem. The wiki article lists several Python libraries implementing it and other such algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what makes it optimal, define a function that depends on cost, qty, ppl and maximize/minimize it.  Then its just optimization.

I'm assuming cost is cost per item, qty is amount available in store, and ppl are minimum number of people for group buy to kick in.  Then minimizing cost*ppl/qty is equivalent to minimizing the minimum total amount spent before it kicks in, divided by the number of people who could participate in the group buy if it becomes available.  But you still have to think does this make sense.  You may say that if the cost doubles, but qty available also doubles that this group-buy is worse than a smaller one.  Maybe if cost doubles, qty would have to increase by 4, or # of ppl necessary decrease by 4.  Then you may want a function like cost^2 ppl/qty.  E.g., something in general like cost^m ppl^n/qty^p should work; you just adjust the m, n, p (all positive numbers) depending on the weights you think appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I didn't make very clear what the numbers actually represented. =) In this case, Cost is a total cost, Qty is the quantity of items included (per person), and Ppl being the number of people required to get that particular deal.